# How should I understand the comment on a declined flag?

Tags: discussion

I flagged a question as "very low quality" and it got declined (no problem there). However the comment "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" seems to imply I did something silly - **did** I?
For the reference the post in question was https://askubuntu.com/questions/244978/password-reset-nothing-works

I don't want to discuss the mod's decision on that flag - it is only the comment which makes me doubt: should I not have flagged the question at all for some (to "everybody" obvious) reason, or should I have used a different flag (like off topic) for another obvious reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question can be edited to make it sane. Probably that was the intent. Just guessing.

Comment: Thats what I tried before flagging it - but I had to give up :-)

Comment: +1 This would be *my* reasoning for declining the flag. **Flags should not be used to get a moderator to do a job that you could.** In this case a more readable version can be hammered out simply by spending some time reading the original. (The exception to the above is things that need dealing with quickly)

Comment: @Oli: understood (though in my opinion it was beyond repair), but I don't want to discuss the decline anyway - your comment makes the comment I was really asking about much clearer for me - I am accepting this answer - thx.